# Creating reports in Excel without PivotTables?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a master Excel file which includes sections of data as well as multiple columns, although all data is in one worksheet. I want to be able to pull information from the file to create nearly custom reports for my boss on demand, which could include reorganizing the sections and selecting specific columns. Sometimes I need to be able to produce this report in less than a minute, so taking the time to reorganize and reformat the report is not an option. We are currently keeping the data in three workbooks, all formatted slightly differently based on the boss' needs, which means updating is a nightmare and prone to mistakes.

Is there an option in Excel to be able to compile intact sections of data from the master file into a new worksheet or workbook without copying and pasting? I'm thinking of something like a dashboard or query that can be built, then refreshed to populate the information.